# No RDS metrics for CPU credit balance and CPU credit use in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS RDS DB.m4.large, Which is not showing the CPU CREDIT BALANCE (COUNT), and CPU CREDIT USES (COUNT) in the Cloudwatch matrices.

[image: Screenshot of RDS MATRIC]

I would appreciate your help in understanding the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU Credit Usage and Balances are only relevant when you use a t-Instance (t2, t3, t4). These are burstable and operate based on credits.

Your m4 instance doesn't use credits because it's not burstable, so the metrics are empty.